# How to query the KnowledgeArticleVersion and Linked Article Objects in sfdc

Tags: soql, query, dynamic-soql

[image]

i get "SELECT id, abdulking__Knowledge_Linked_Artical__c
           ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:12
No such column 'abdulking__Knowledge_Linked_Artical__c' on entity 'KnowledgeArticleVersion'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names." 
This above ERROR how to fetch all Fields From **KnowledgeArticleVersion** Object.

Note: If you have any idea give examples other wise leave it.. Don't give Nagative Mark ... Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have create an article type name `xyz` then KnowledgeArticleVersion API name will be `xyz_kav`.

For more information, refer [KnowledgeArticleVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleversion.htm)

Here is an example from documentation.

```
SELECT Id, Title
FROM Offer__kav
WHERE PublishStatus='Draft'
AND Language = 'en_US'
WITH DATA CATEGORY Geography__c AT (france__c,usa__c) AND Product__c ABOVE dsl__c
```

Comment: Thanks u r Replay, i tried this query its working, But i,m asking How to use Custom Fields in KnowledgeArticleVersion Object.

Comment: KnowledgeArticleVersion object doesn't allow to create custom fields, though we can able to create custom fields in Article Types

Comment: Yes, i already Did that one, Creating a Field in article but i need to Query the article Custom Fields in KnowledgeArticleVersion...
 give me any some Examples ... above i mention screen shot please refer... my "Linked Article Fields"

Comment: Hi @Santanu Boral ..... I have a two articles, like Offer__kav and Offer_order__kav , How to Query This Two Objects Related All Fields.... Please give any suggestion. For Ex: i tried ::: List<List<SObject>> search_results = [FIND 'SFDC' RETURNING abdulking__Baahubali_2_Artical__kav(Title), abdulking__Baahubali Artical_1(Title,)];
This is Not Working....

Comment: Can you post a separate question taking this comment